# URL without www redirect directly with submission page - Multiwordpress install

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess, rewrite-rules

This is a Wordpress related question, because the problem came from a multi-install Wordpress. But it's also related to serverside, with .htaccess

**My problem is** : when a user type my URL without *WWW*, it get him/her to an submission URL, inviting him/her to log-in. From https://mister-tea.fr to an URL like this https://www.fixie-lille.fr/wp-signup.php?new=mister-tea.fr instead of https://www.mister-tea.fr

I really don't want it, I just want that the user is redirected to the same domain, and the same URL with *WWW*.

My main domain is https://www.fixie-lille.fr (Fr website)

The rule could work :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fixie-lille.fr$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.fixie-lille.fr/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it breaks other website.

I tried using some rules in .htaccess, but does not seems to work.
All my websites use *WWW* domains and are not available without *WWW*.

Beside that, I use this rule to redirect user between http and https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Does the following rule could have a bad interference ?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Beside that, everything works fine wtih several Wordpress in just one install.

Thanks per advance,
I'm at your disposal to answer further questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have multiple domains you can't include the domain in the redirect itself to create a one-size-fits-all generic redirect (which is what I assume you are trying to do). You also need to ensure that the directives are in the correct order.

Since all your sites use the `www` subdomain then try the following instead. However, this assumes you don't have any other subdomains.

```
RewriteEngine On

# non-www to www (and HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# HTTP to HTTPS 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# WordPress directives follow...
```

The non-www to www redirect now tests if the requested host does not start `www`. And if not, simply prepends it.

No need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive and no need for the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrappers on your custom directives.

With regards to your HTTP to HTTPS redirect, there's no need to capture the `RewriteRule` *pattern* if it is not being used in the *substitution*. ie. When using `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of a backreference.

As always, clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I was AFK from several days ... sorry! I'll try it this evening or tomorrow.